# Excel: AVERAGEIFS with pairs of criteria linked, AND not working

Tags: excel, average

I have an AVERAGEIFS formula for multiple criteria.  For certain pairs of the criteria I want it to only average when BOTH are true.  This is my current formula:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('NA Trades'!$R$3:$R$1048576,'NA Trades'!$C$3:$C$1048576,"TSX D3",'NA Trades'!$DW$3:$DW$1048576,">16",'NA Trades'!$Z$3:$Z$1048576,"<20",'NA Trades'!$BB$3:$BB$1048576,"<5.25",'NA Trades'!$AA$3:$AA$1048576,">240000000",'NA Trades'!$BB$3:$BB$1048576,">5.25",'NA Trades'!$CQ$3:$CQ$1048576,"<14.55")
```

The last 4 criteria are the ones I want to have linked in pairs

I only want it to apply then 'NA Trades'!$AA$3:$AA$1048576,">240000000" criteria when 'NA Trades'!$BB$3:$BB$1048576,"<5.25"  and only apply the 'NA Trades'!$CQ$3:$CQ$1048576,"<14.55" criteria when 'NA Trades'!$BB$3:$BB$1048576,">5.25".    (So if BB is >5.25 the AA>240000000 criteria does not matter and when BB is <5.25 the CQ <14.55 does not matter)

I did this by adding an additional column in my data set to identify when the pairs of criteria are true and just including that in the averageifs instead. However I'm trying to figure out how to do this without adding the additional column and do it just in the AVERAGEIFS itself.  I tried nesting and AND to pair the criteria but keep getting an error.

Comment: Are the entries in columns AA and BB non-negative?

Comment: Yes all values are non-negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more concise option would be to switch to an **array formula****:

`=AVERAGE(IF('NA Trades'!$C$3:$C$20="TSX D3",IF('NA Trades'!$DW$3:$DW$20>16,IF('NA Trades'!$Z$3:$Z$20<20,IF(IF('NA Trades'!$BB$3:$BB$20<5.25,'NA Trades'!$AA$3:$AA$20>240000000,1),IF(IF('NA Trades'!$BB$3:$BB$20>5.25,'NA Trades'!$CQ$3:$CQ$20<14.55,1),'NA Trades'!$R$3:$R$20))))))`

though in that case you would be strongly advised **not to use entire column references**; hence my choice of an upper row reference of 20 (which you can obviously increase as required, though be sure to keep it as low as possible).

Alternatively, you can use a combination of `SUMIFS`/`COUNTIFS`, which is less concise though which has the benefit that referencing entire columns has virtually no detriment to performance:

`=SUM(SUMIFS('NA Trades'!$R$3:$R$1048576,'NA Trades'!$C$3:$C$1048576,"TSX D3",'NA Trades'!$DW$3:$DW$1048576,">16",'NA Trades'!$Z$3:$Z$1048576,"<20",'NA Trades'!$BB$3:$BB$1048576,{"<",">="}&5.25,'NA Trades'!$AA$3:$AA$1048576,{">240000000",">=0"},'NA Trades'!$BB$3:$BB$1048576,{"<=",">"}&5.25,'NA Trades'!$CQ$3:$CQ$1048576,{">=0","<14.55"}))/SUM(COUNTIFS('NA Trades'!$C$3:$C$1048576,"TSX D3",'NA Trades'!$DW$3:$DW$1048576,">16",'NA Trades'!$Z$3:$Z$1048576,"<20",'NA Trades'!$BB$3:$BB$1048576,{"<",">="}&5.25,'NA Trades'!$AA$3:$AA$1048576,{">240000000",">=0"},'NA Trades'!$BB$3:$BB$1048576,{"<=",">"}&5.25,'NA Trades'!$CQ$3:$CQ$1048576,{">=0","<14.55"}))`

By the way, are there values in rows 1 and 2 which would prevent you from referencing the columns in their entirety for the sake of abbreviating the latter? If not, use:

`=SUM(SUMIFS('NA Trades'!$R:$R,'NA Trades'!$C:$C,"TSX D3",'NA Trades'!$DW:$DW,">16",'NA Trades'!$Z:$Z,"<20",'NA Trades'!$BB:$BB,{"<",">="}&5.25,'NA Trades'!$AA:$AA,{">240000000",">=0"},'NA Trades'!$BB:$BB,{"<=",">"}&5.25,'NA Trades'!$CQ:$CQ,{">=0","<14.55"}))/SUM(COUNTIFS('NA Trades'!$C:$C,"TSX D3",'NA Trades'!$DW:$DW,">16",'NA Trades'!$Z:$Z,"<20",'NA Trades'!$BB:$BB,{"<",">="}&5.25,'NA Trades'!$AA:$AA,{">240000000",">=0"},'NA Trades'!$BB:$BB,{"<=",">"}&5.25,'NA Trades'!$CQ:$CQ,{">=0","<14.55"}))`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Thank you, the sumif countif solution works.  The data set is quite large and gets bigger each day which is why i need to use entire column references.

Comment: Ok, then probably the sensible choice, though a touch more difficult to understand syntactically perhaps.